# jQuery find gives undefined

Tags: jquery, onchange, closest

I have 2 input boxes for start and end times. I use UIKit timepicker. When I try to get the closest end time value when start time change, it shows undefined. Why it is so?
Here is my code so far

```
$('.start_time').on('change', function() {
            var end = $(this).closest('div').find('.end_time').val();
            var start = $(this).val();
            alert(end);
            if(end<=start){
                $(this).closest('div').find('.end_time').val('');
            }
        });
```

Here is my html part (But not full html code)

```
<div class="uk-width-1-4 start-time-div">
                                        <label class="uk-form-label uk-display-block">Start Time</label>
                                        <div class="uk-form-controls uk-clearfix">
                                            <div class="yn_formdatewrap">
                                                <div class="uk-form-icon uk-form-icon-flip uk-width-1-1">
                                                    <i class="yash_icons yash-ion-android-time"></i>
                                                    <input type="text" name="start_time[]" placeholder="Start Time" data-uk-timepicker="{format:'12h'}" 
                                                    class="uk-width-1-1 yn_formcommon yn_formtext timing-req start_time">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="uk-width-1-4 end-time-div">
                                        <label class="uk-form-label uk-display-block">End Time</label>
                                        <div class="uk-form-controls uk-clearfix">
                                            <div class="yn_formdatewrap">
                                                <div class="uk-form-icon uk-form-icon-flip uk-width-1-1">
                                                    <i class="yash_icons yash-ion-android-time"></i>
                                                    <input type="text" name="end_time[]" placeholder="End Time" data-uk-timepicker="{format:'12h'}" 
                                                    class="uk-width-1-1 yn_formcommon yn_formtext timing-req end_time">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.end_time` lies in next sibling div of `.start_time` elements closest parent div `div.stat-time-div`. thus you need to target next div with class `end-time-div` and then find end date in it:

```
var end = $(this).closest('.start-time-div').next().find('.end_time').val();.val();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bqgLvbbf/)**

Comment: Sorry. I have updated the question. I have few others divs in between them

Comment: Still not working. I have updated the question with my actual html

Comment: @Corner: you had typo in older html. check the answer now.